# How can I take out the an element from a list in a list

Tags: java, arraylist, nested-lists

I am working on java code and here I want to know how can take out the element from a list which is inside a list and I know the index of the list stored.
I know you won't understand by this, so here is the code.

```
public static List<ArrayList> dnList = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm1n = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm2n = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm3n = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm4n = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm5n = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm6n = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm7n = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm8n = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm9n = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<Integer> dm10n = new ArrayList<>();
```

> So here the first list you have contains all other lists.

Now I have a variable ln which contain the index of the dnList in which the element I want is and another
variable index which contain the index of actual list.

> Note : The element I want is actually in one of the list from dm1n to dm10n and they all are stored in dnList. Variable ln contain a index in dnList and variable index contain a index in the actual list.

I have tried this -

```
int element = dnList.get(ln).get(index)
```

But it didn't work so I want something else.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what actually didn't work?

Comment: Thanks for asking, but I have got my answer.

Comment: @AntonTokmakov, if I understand well the problem is that `dnList` has been not declared as `List<List<Integer>>`, so a cast to `Integer` is necessary.

Comment: Yeah, that was the mistake I made

Comment: @dariosicily Oh, ok, thanks for adding extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
int element = (Integer)(dnList.get(ln)).get(index);
```

Comment: It really helped me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Abra Typecast is required because the `dnList` is declared as `List<ArrayList>` and not `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`

Comment: _`dnList` is declared as `List<ArrayList>` and not `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`_ which means that a cast to `int` is sufficient. By the way, this works for me: `int val = (int) dnList.get(ln).get(index);`